# DHCP v6 Server как задать pool

Tags: linux, dhcp, ipv6, pool

Серверу принтер гасит пингами дай адрес и всё. Каждые две минуты.

```
12:13:35 dhcpd[2015]: Solicit message from fe80::225:b3ff:fef2:**** port 546, transaction ID 0x83A2B500  
12:13:35 dhcpd[2015]: Unable to pick client address: no IPv6 pools on this shared network  
12:13:35 dhcpd[2015]: Sending Advertise to fe80::225:b3ff:fef2:**** port 546  
12:15:35 dhcpd[2015]: Solicit message from fe80::225:b3ff:fef2:**** port 546, transaction ID 0x83A2B500  
12:15:35 dhcpd[2015]: Unable to pick client address: no IPv6 pools on this shared network  
12:15:35 dhcpd[2015]: Sending Advertise to fe80::225:b3ff:fef2:**** port 546
```

Принтер на два адреса на пинг отвечает по сетям `fd00::***` и `2a03:****`. И он живой и печатает. Почему сервер не может найти pool? Вот так настроил dhcpd6.conf :

```
shared-network LOCAL1 {  
 subnet6 fd00:a000::/64 {  
  range6 fd00:a000::/64 temporary;  
 }  
 subnet6 2a03:e2c0:***:6666::/64 {  
  range6 2a03:e2c0:***:6666:: temporary;  
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо было просто дать два адреса. Постоянный и временный. Принтер угомонился.

dhcpd6.conf :

```
shared-network LOCAL1 {  
 subnet6 fd00:a000::/64 {  
  range6 fd00:a000::0 fd00:a000::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff;
  range6 fd00:a000::/64 temporary;  
 }  
 subnet6 2a03:e2c0:***:6666::/64 {  
  range6 2a03:e2c0:***:6666::0 2a03:e2c0:***:6666:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff;
  range6 2a03:e2c0:***:6666:: temporary;  
 }  
}
```